# I am trying to split data into 4 equal sized groups,. The data is in 1 column, but some cells are blank and I dont want it to count the blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

=AV4&","&ROUNDUP((ROW()-3)/(COUNT($AV$4:$BK$2498)/4),0)

I am using this formula which works beautifully without any blank cells.

Is there a way of amending the formula to discount any empty cells, so that I still only end up with 4 equal sized groups?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g38KX.png)

I have also tried adding to the start of the formula =IF(AV4<>"",

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g38KX.png)

But either way I am not getting the desired result.

There are exactly 1465 cells with data in, which i would like to then return me 4 groups of 366.

However, there's a total of 2495 rows that are being looked at

Comment: In which row is this formula located and what is the expected result? If you have the numbers from 1 to 10 in `A1:A10`, what should be returned and where? Adding a screenshot to your post would certainly help.

Comment: I've just amended my original question, and added some images, so perhaps this might help?

Comment: Both links point to the same image. If you group like you're saying, the 1465th item will be not accounted for. IMO, the group size should be 367, with the last group containing only 364 items.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77034307) is a similar post where I address the issue.

Answer (score 1):

### Split Data Into Equal Sized Groups

- The screenshot also illustrates how the formula behaves when the requirement is not possible i.e. when the number of (non-blank) rows is not divisible by the number of groups.

[image]

```
=LET(data,A4:A13,Groups,4,Dlm,",",
    df,FILTER(data,data<>""),
    rc,ROWS(df),
df&Dlm&ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(rc)/ROUNDUP(rc/Groups,),))
```

**Study Version**

- Replace the last `dr` with any of the other variables to better understand the formula.

```
=LET(data,A4:A13,Groups,4,Dlm,",",
    df,FILTER(data,data<>""),
    rc,ROWS(df),
    gs,ROUNDUP(rc/Groups,),
    ds,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(rc)/gs,),
    dr,df&Dlm&ds,
dr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in B4 and drag down:

```
=IF(A4<>"",A4 & "," & ROUNDUP((ROW()-COUNTBLANK($A$1:A4))/(COUNTA(A:A)/4),0),"")
```

It counts the empty cells above the current row and subtracts them.
The starting point of `COUNTBLANK` is absolut address - but the end of the range is relative.